# Auto Complete not working for Angular2 Visual Studio code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have installed the tsd for angular2 and added it as reference using
`/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />`
But still not getting anything inside @view and @component [image]

Comment: Complete and working d.ts for Angular 2 still a problem.